# @IfProfileValue vs @ActiveProfiles in the context of Spring test

Tags: spring-test

I am in reference to **Spring test** and the following annotations:

- [**`@IfProfileValue`**](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/test/annotation/IfProfileValue.html)
- [**`@ActiveProfiles`**](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/test/context/ActiveProfiles.html)

I currently use **`@ActiveProfiles`** in my application and I recently discovered the existence of the **`@IfProfileValue`** annotation which seems to provide similar functionnality.

Can someone please explain what the differences are between those two annotations perhaps by providing usage examples that would contrast the two?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As stated in the Javadoc, `@IfProfileValue` is used *to indicate that a test is enabled for a specific testing profile or environment.*

Whereas, `@ActiveProfiles` is used *to declare which active bean definition profiles should be used when loading an ApplicationContext for test classes.*

In other words, you use `@IfProfileValue` to **control** whether a test class or test method will be *executed* or *skipped*, and you use `@ActiveProfiles` to **set** the active bean definition profiles that will be used to *load* the `ApplicationContext` for your test.

Please note that `@IfProfileValue` was introduced in Spring Framework 2.0, **long** before the notion of *bean definition profiles*, and `@ActiveProfiles` was first introduced in Spring Framework 3.1.

Both annotations contain the term *profile*, but they are actually completely unrelated!

The term *profile* is perhaps misleading when considering the semantics for `@IfProfileValue`. The key is to think about *test groups* (like those in TestNG) instead of *profiles*. See the examples in the [JavaDoc for @IfProfileValue](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/test/annotation/IfProfileValue.html). Here's an excerpt:

```
@IfProfileValue(name = "test-groups", values = { "unit-tests", "integration-tests" })
public void testWhichRunsForUnitOrIntegrationTestGroups() {
    // ...
}
```

The above test method would be executed if you set the `test-groups` system property (e.g., `-Dtest-groups=unit-tests` or `-Dtest-groups=integration-tests`).

The [Context configuration with environment profiles](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-env-profiles) section of the *Testing* chapter in the Spring Reference manual provides detailed examples of how to use `@ActiveProfiles`.

Regards,

Sam (author of the Spring TestContext Framework)

Comment: "profile" does seem very overloaded in the annotations, in fact I'm not sure what `@IfProfileValue` has to do with profiles at all. Even the way to make it check a profile doesn't seem obvious. And using `@Profile` to filter, and `@ActiveProfiles` to provide is counter intuitive.