# How can I use @IfProfileValue to test if a Profile is active?

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-test

So confusingly `@IfProfileValue` has nothing to do with `@Profile` or `@ActiveProfiles`. `@Profile` tests to see if a profile is active, `@ActiveProfiles` sets them as active, and `@IfProfileValue` allows you to check things in Spring `Environment`. Wut? I'd deprecate all of them and add new ones `@IfEnvironment`, `@IfProfile`, and `@ActivateProfiles`.

Commentary aside, how can I use `@IfProfileValue` to detect whether i have a profile active? I am not using Spring Boot on this project, at this time. Answers should show code, and we will assume that I want the test to run if the profile is activated as `@ActiveProfiles( "test" )`.

I tried `@IfProfileValue(name = "activeProfiles", value = "test")` but that seems to have the test skipped, which means it's not matching. I'm going to speculate the problem may have to do with the fact that `ActiveProfiles` is a `Collection`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> So confusingly `@IfProfileValue` has nothing to do with `@Profile` or
>   `@ActiveProfiles`.

That's correct, and I explained this in detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23627479/388980

... which I'm assuming you have already seen, since you commented on my answer yesterday.

The reason that `@IfProfileValue` has nothing to do with `@Profile` or `@ActiveProfiles` is due to the evolution of the framework. See below for further details.

> `@Profile` tests to see if a profile is active,
>   `@ActiveProfiles` sets them as active, and `@IfProfileValue` allows
>   you to check things in Spring `Environment`.

These statements are not entirely correct, especially the last part.

`@Profile` is used to selectively enable a component (e.g., `@Service`, etc.), `@Configuration` class, or `@Bean` method if one of the named *bean definition profiles* is active in the Spring `Environment` for the `ApplicationContext`. This annotation is not directly related to testing: `@Profile` should *not* be used on a test class.

`@ActiveProfiles` is used to designate which *bean definition profiles* (e.g., those declared via `@Profile`) should be active when loading an `ApplicationContext` for an integration test.

`@IfProfileValue` does **not** allow you to check things in the Spring `Environment`. I'm not sure why you are assuming this, since none of the documentation in the Spring Framework states that. As I stated in the aforementioned thread:

*Please note that `@IfProfileValue` was introduced in Spring Framework 2.0, **long** before the notion of bean definition profiles, and `@ActiveProfiles` was first introduced in Spring Framework 3.1.*

In the aforementioned thread, I also pointed out the following:

*The term 'profile' is perhaps misleading when considering the semantics for `@IfProfileValue`. The key is to think about 'test groups' (like those in TestNG) instead of 'profiles'. See the examples in the [JavaDoc for @IfProfileValue](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/test/annotation/IfProfileValue.html).*

> how can I use `@IfProfileValue` to detect whether i have a profile active?

That depends, and... I'm assuming you mean *bean definition profile* when you say "profile".

If you're using `@ActiveProfiles` to set the *bean definition profiles* for your tests, you cannot currently use `@IfProfileValue` to determine if a *bean definition profile* is active, since the *bean definition profiles* configured via `@ActiveProfiles` are set directly in the test's `ApplicationContext` and not as a Java system property.

However, if you are setting the *bean definition profiles* **only** via the `spring.profiles.active` system property, then it *would* be possible to use `@IfProfileValue` to determine if a *bean definition profile* is active, since `@IfProfileValue` in fact works with system properties. For example, you could then use the following:

```java
@IfProfileValue(name = "spring.profiles.active", value = "test")
```

> I tried `@IfProfileValue(name = "activeProfiles", value = "test")` but
>   that seems to have the test skipped, which means it's not matching.

That won't work since `activeProfiles` is the incorrect property name. The correct system property name is `spring.profiles.active`. See `AbstractEnvironment.ACTIVE_PROFILES_PROPERTY_NAME` for details.

---

The fact that `@IfProfileValue` does not work in harmony with `@ActiveProfiles` is a known issue to the Spring team. Please consult the following JIRA issues for further details and to join in on the discussions if you'd like.

- https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-7754
- https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8982
- https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11677

Hope this clarifies the situation for you!

Sam (*author of the Spring TestContext Framework*)

Comment: I think I got the "environment" idea from one of the  jira/SO threads... I also may have assumed that it was using the property source merger thing, which, afaik, would allow access to the environment as well. My mistake. I get that there are historical reasons for the naming differences, which is why I would deprecate them all in v5, and give them new names. I find all of the annotations to have uses that aren't obvious by looking at the code that is using them.

Comment: One feedback is that if you have more than one active profile then checking the `spring.profiles.active` against a specific profile would fail as there is multiple, comma separated, profile names.

Comment: Could you point out why `@Profile` should not be used on a test class? Please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/53313489/4106030

Answer (score 6):

Sam nailed it. (As well as the fact this was accepted and answered years back)

One thing to add is that if you'd like to pass System Properties through to your test, having them propagate through to the JVM if you are using a build tool like gradle may require an additional step.

```
//build.gradle
tasks.withType(Test) {
    systemProperties System.properties
}
```

And then business as usual in your integration test

```
//MyIntegrationTest.class
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("integration")
@IfProfileValue(name = "run.integration.tests", value = "true")
public class MyIntegrationTest {
    @Test
    public void myTest(){ ... }
}
```

Finally you can execute your tests from the terminal with the property you specified.

```
$> ./gradlew clean test -Drun.integration.tests=true
```

The thing I like most about `@IfProfileValue` over grabbing the System.property and checking `assumeTrue/False` manually is that no Spring Context is loaded (or flyway/other migrations you may have) keeping unit tests fast.

Comment: That all being said, I realize I injected "integration testing" here and that wasn't really mentioned in OP.

Comment: eh, we're using it for integration testing with upstream API providers, to avoid abusing their API every time a test runs.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, from my experience, test dependency on @IfProfileValue

```
@Test
@IfProfileValue(name="spring.profiles.active", values={"test"})
```

Will work only when you set spring.profiles.active as a JVM property, as:
    -Dspring.profiles.active="test"

```
@IfProfileValue just ignores spring.profiles.active from application.properties/yml.
```

Comment: Confirmed.  Another important node: the ['OR' Semantics](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#integration-testing-annotations-junit4-ifprofilevalue) of `@IfProfileValue` must be used when testing property `name="spring.profiles.active"`.  So `@IfProfileValue(name="spring.profiles.active", values={"test"})` works but `@IfProfileValue(name="spring.profiles.active", value="test")` will not.

Comment: For junit5, the following annotation may be necessary instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53718280/2695203

Answer (score 0):

When using junit5 it is possible to conditionally enable the test based on the active profile:

```
@EnabledIf(expression =
   "#{environment.acceptsProfiles(T(org.springframework.core.env.Profiles).of('someprofile'))}",
   loadContext = true)
class MyTest {
   ...
}
```

This checks if `someprofile` is active and unlike checking for `spring.profiles.active` property works event if there are more than one profile enabled. This checks if `someprofile` is among currently active profiles.

In order to make this more readable it is possible to use spring meta-annotation. Define annotation first

```
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@EnabledIf(expression =
  "#{environment.acceptsProfiles(T(org.springframework.core.env.Profiles).of('someprofile'))}",
  loadContext = true)
public @interface EnabledIfSomeProfile {
}
```

And then use it on test classes:

```
@EnableIfSomeProfile
class MyTest {
 ...
}
```