# Use @Profile to decide to execute test class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test, spring-profiles

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/33042872/4106030 
we should not use `@Profile` to let a spring profile decide whether all tests in a test class shall be executed or ignored.

There is stated:

> `@Profile` is used to selectively enable a component (e.g., `@Service`, etc.), `@Configuration` class, or `@Bean` method if one of the named bean definition profiles is active in the Spring Environment for the ApplicationContext. This annotation is not directly related to testing: **`@Profile` should not be used on a test class**.

Is this true? If yes then why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's true because `@Profile` effects Spring components and not connected to Test framework.

Nevertheless, you can have test profile which will load Spring components ( as Configuration classes) when you running tests

Example of Test class with profile:

```
// load related configuration classes
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { TestConfiguration.class }) 
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = { "testing" })
public class MyTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {
```

Comment: But it does work... Can you show what you mean by having a test profile? What I need is just a simple way to decide by a spring profile whether some specific test classes are executed or not.

Comment: @badera you exclude tests using testng/junit tools. add test class with profile

Comment: Can you show how? - the source of decision should be if a spring profile is set or not

Comment: I am very confused because `@ActiveProfiles` sets the current profile and does not make the execution of tests depending on, if the listed profile is set or not. At least this is what I actually observe to happen and what is also written in https://stackoverflow.com/a/33042872/4106030

Comment: @badera the comment you asked in your question is only about `@Profile` which isn't present in my test class