# @IfProfileValue not working with JUnit 5 SpringExtension

Tags: spring-boot, junit, spring-test, junit5, spring-profiles

I use junit5 with spring-starter-test, in order to run spring test I need to use `@ExtendWith` instead of `@RunWith`. However `@IfProfileValue` work with `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` but not with `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)`, below is my code:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith({SpringExtension.class})
class MyApplicationTests{

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Application Context should be loaded")
    @IfProfileValue(name = "test-groups" , value="unit-test")
    void contextLoads() {
    }
}
```

so the contextLoads should be ignore since it didn't specify the env test-grooups. but the test just run and ignore the `@IfProfileValue`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found out that `@IfProfileValue` only support for junit4, in junit5 we will use `@EnabledIf` and `@DisabledIf`.

Reference https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#integration-testing-annotations-meta

Update: Thanks to @SamBrannen'scomment, so I use junit5 build-in support with regex matches and make it as an Annotation.

```
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@EnabledIfSystemProperty(named = "test-groups", matches = "(.*)unit-test(.*)")
public @interface EnableOnIntegrationTest {}
```

so any test method or class with this annotion will run only when they have a system property of test-groups which contains unit test.

```
@Test
@DisplayName("Application Context should be loaded")
@EnableOnIntegrationTest
void contextLoads() {
}
```

Comment: That's correct. However, if you're using JUnit Jupiter 5.1 or higher and you want to check a JVM system property, the best choice is the built-in support for `@EnabledIfSystemProperty` and `@DisabledIfSystemProperty`.