# Is it possible to mark springboot tests so they run only when certain profile is active

Tags: java, testing, spring-boot

I have two profiles: dev and default. And I would like to skip some (not all) tests when the active profile is default.
Is it possible to mark these tests somehow to do so? Or how can this be achieved?
I use springboot. This is my parent test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyServiceStarter.class, webEnvironment= SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT,
        properties = {"flyway.locations=filesystem:../database/h2", "server.port=9100", "spring.profiles.default=dev"})
@Category(IntegrationTest.class)
public abstract class AbstractModuleIntegrationTest { ... }
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

My colleague found a solution:
so if you need to annotate separate tests you can use the `@IfProfileValue` annotation:

```
@IfProfileValue(name ="spring.profiles.active", value ="default")
    @Test
    public void testSomething() {
        //testing logic
    }
```

This test will run only when default profile is active

UPDATE:
For Junit 5 use:

```
@EnabledIfSystemProperty(named = "spring.profiles.active", matches = "default")
```

More info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#integration-testing-annotations-meta

Comment: You can use the annotation in the whole class if you need it.

Comment: Note that if you run test in Gradle and pass the system property as `-D` parameter to Gradle, it invokes another JVM in tests and doesn't pass the property to it by default. Hence the test will be skipped thanks to `EnabledIfSystemProperty` annotation. The solution is to pass system property to newly invoked JVM - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/35320306/653539 answer and its question.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can do it.

For example use `@ActiveProfiles`:

```
@ActiveProfiles("default")
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class YourTest {
   //tests
}
```

Comment: but this will deactivate all tests in the class. Is it possible to deactivate only several tests?

Comment: This is wrong. "@IfProfileValue" does not decide whether a test runs or not. It only decides which beans definition profiles should be used when the test runs. "@IfProfileValue" should be used as in the accepted answer. For detailed explanation see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23607489/ifprofilevalue-vs-activeprofiles-in-the-context-of-spring-test/

Answer (score 3):

`@IfProfileValue` only works for JUnit 4. If you're on JUnit 5, as you should be by this time, use `@EnabledIf` or `@DisabledIf`.

Example:

```
@DisabledIf(
    expression = "#{systemProperties['os.name'].toLowerCase().contains('mac')}",
    reason = "Disabled on Mac OS"
)
```

See [the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#integration-testing-annotations-junit-jupiter) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to run the tests from the command line using below:

```
SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev ./gradlew test
```

and none of the above works for you, you can use below annotation (on a class or single test method):

```
@DisabledIfEnvironmentVariable(named = "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE", matches = "(dev|default|local)")
```

The test will be disabled if the spring profile is set to `dev` or `default` or `local` (regular expression)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this profile based condition:

```
@EnabledIf(value = "#{'${spring.profiles.active}' == 'test'}", loadContext = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another alternative for JUnit 5.9.x. This will only work on test methods and not on the class level as in that case the `isProfileActive` needs to be `static` . :

```java
@SpringBootTest
public class SomeTest {

    @Autowired
    Environment environment;

    @Test
    @DisabledIf("isProfileActive")
    void testMethod() {}

    boolean isProfileActive() {
        return Arrays.stream(this.environment.getActiveProfiles()).toList().contains("myprofile");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers have worked for me, and look incorrect at a glance (e.g. comparing a list to a string or expecting profiles to be declared via the one system property)

The following actually works:

```
@EnabledIf(expression = "#{environment.acceptsProfiles('preprod')}", loadContext = true)
```

Unfortunately, as of Spring 5.3.23 (that I happen to be using) `Environment::acceptsProfiles(String...)` is marked as deprecated in favour of `Environment::acceptsProfiles(Profiles...)`. However the `Profiles of(String...)` doesn't work in an expression and leads to the following error.

`Property or field 'Profiles' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public or not valid`

If someone knows a way around this, please correct my answer.