# How to use feature flags to disable application.properties setting

Tags: spring-boot, feature-flags

I understand that I can use `@ConditionalOnExpression` to enable or disable a component such as a `@RestController`, or `@Service`, or `@Entity`.  That is all clear.

However, Spring Boot has more.  It has **application.properties** configuration, it has `@Autowired` properties, it has `@Test` classes/methods.

For example, given I have feature flag defined in my **application.properties** file as:

```
myFeature.enabled=false
```

I want to disabled following:

- **database connectivity settings in **application.properties****

```
    // I want to disable all these using myFeature.enabled flag
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/db_example
    spring.datasource.username=springuser
    spring.datasource.password=ThePassword
    spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    #spring.jpa.show-sql: true
```

- **an`@Autowired` property in a class and I only want to disable that one injected property**

```java
    @Component
    public class FooService {  
        @Autowired
        private Foo foo; // I want to disable only this property using myFeature.enabled flag
    }
```

- **Test class and I want to disable it (I know I can use `@Ignore` or `@Disable`) using myFeature.enabled flag**

```java
    @SpringBootTest
    public class EmployeeRestControllerIntegrationTest {
    
        ...
    
        // tests methods
    }
```

How do I disable these using `myFeature.enabled` flag?

I know that in case of an @Entity or @Controller class I can simply do something like below, but I dont know how to use same mechanism to disable the 3 above cases:

```
@Entity
@ConditionalOnExpression(${myFeature.enabled})
public class Employee {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From your question, I think using [spring profiles](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles) is a much better fit. With profiles you can:

- have an application-{profile}.properties file containing profile-specific properties that are only used if the profile is active.
- You can choose to enable a specific implementation of your FooService and disable the default version if a profile is active.
- You can [enable a test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43851621/is-it-possible-to-mark-springboot-tests-so-they-run-only-when-certain-profile-is) only if the profile is active.

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of profiles, I use them already but that is not what I am looking for.  I  am asking about feature flags