# ActiveProfile is not working in Junit5 test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, junit5

I want to set Spring Profile in order to test different sets of JUnit tests. I tried this:

application.properties:

```
spring.profiles.active=dev
```

test 1

```
@IfProfileValue(name = "spring.profiles.active", values = {"test"})
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = {"test"})
public class SecondGenericTest {

    @Test
    public void secGenericTest() {

        System.out.println("Performing test ... for profile test");
    }
}
```

test 2

```
@IfProfileValue(name = "spring.profiles.active", values = {"test"})
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = {"test"})
public class SecondGenericTest {

    @Test
    public void secGenericTest() {

        System.out.println("Performing test ... for profile test");
    }
}
```

Tried to set also into InteliJ Active profile:

[image]

But every time both tests are executed. Is there some solution to run the test with the proper active profile?

POM configuration:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-bean-validators</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
            <artifactId>woodstox-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.reactivex.rxjava2</groupId>
            <artifactId>rxjava</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--  Dependency for for Netty. Remove it when WebFlux is not used -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-transport-native-epoll</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.45.Final</version>
            <classifier>linux-x86_64</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Packages for testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-commons</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>test</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Dependencies>jdk.unsupported</Dependencies>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>12</release>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>repository.spring.release</id>
            <name>Spring GA Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype-releases</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>java.net</id>
            <url>https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/public/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>JBoss repository</id>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jvnet-nexus-snapshots</id>
            <name>jvnet-nexus-snapshots</name>
            <url>https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

Comment: You have asked exactly the same question several hours ago and it was closed as duplicate. Do not spam this site like this.

Comment: The solution from the link is not working so I followed the recommendation of SO to open new question.

Comment: Try `@IfProfileValue(name = "spring.profiles.active", value = "test")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained by Sam Brannen in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23607489/ifprofilevalue-vs-activeprofiles-in-the-context-of-spring-test/23627479#23627479):

> As stated in the Javadoc, `@IfProfileValue` is used to indicate that a
>   test is enabled for a specific testing profile or environment.
>
> Whereas, `@ActiveProfiles` is used to declare which active bean
>   definition profiles should be used when loading an ApplicationContext
>   for test classes.
>
> In other words, you use `@IfProfileValue` to control whether a test
>   class or test method will be executed or skipped, and you use
>   @ActiveProfiles to set the active bean definition profiles that will
>   be used to load the ApplicationContext for your test.

So in your case `@ActiveProfile` should do the trick.

Also JUnit 5 allows you to add tags to your tests, functionality which can help you run only certain tests.

You can do this by using the `@Tag("...")` annotation, and set it as a parameter for your [configuration](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-tag-expressions), by changing the test kind to tags as you choose

Also you can configure tags via maven for building/releasing via

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
        <configuration>
            <!-- include tags -->
            <groups>integration, feature-168</groups>
            <!-- exclude tags -->
            <excludedGroups>slow</excludedGroups>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

[image]

Comment: @ActiveProfile? I get - Cannot resolve symbol 'ActiveProfile'

Comment: @ActiveProfiles, and also you should run your tests with the spring runner, by using: @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)

Comment: I tried with `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = {"test"})` but again every JUnit is run; Any idea why might be missing?

Comment: If you want to exlude only certain tests you could use the junit5 tag feature

Comment: Can you share more what is this?

Comment: With the @Tag, you can create customized test plans. We use this for example, in our app to mark some integration tests as unstable, and skip them in a ci/cd  environment. Check this https://howtodoinjava.com/junit5/junit-5-tag-annotation-example/ for a more detailed explanation

Comment: The best way of achieving this segregation(separation) of tests(per environment:test, acceptance,production) could be by using the `@Tag` feature and just set an jvm environment variable on each machine

Comment: ok, so I can use tag to execute specific test. Just one thing is not clear. Into InteliJ where I can set which JUnit with tag name should be executed?

Comment: I added a explanation in the answer please check it.

Comment: Thanks. Last question: I can use tags during development to test different Junit tests when they are needed. But if I want to make final build of the jar how I can skip some of the JUnit tests which I don't want to run?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the correct syntax should be

```
@IfProfileValue(name = "spring.profiles.active", value = "test")
```

Default implementation of class, which accompanies `@IfProfileValue` annotation is `ProfileValueSource`  class, which looks in system properties - therefore you need to set profile via JVM properties, i.e. -`-Dspring.profiles.active="test"`

Unfortunately `@IfProfileValue` does not account for values specified via `@ActiveProfiles` or by `@Profile`

[Javadocs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/annotation/IfProfileValue.html):

> Although the @IfProfileValue and @Profile annotations both involve
>   profiles, they are not directly related. @Profile involves bean
>   definition profiles configured in the Environment; whereas,
>   @IfProfileValue is used to enable or disable tests.

You can see default implementation class [at Github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-test/src/main/java/org/springframework/test/annotation/SystemProfileValueSource.java)

Which looks for keys in System properties

```
@Override
public String get(String key) {
    Assert.hasText(key, "'key' must not be empty");
    return System.getProperty(key);
}
```

So we can see that actually we do not have to set spring profile specifically, it can be any environment variable, that can be resolved by `System.getProperty(key);` call, i.e `test.active.profile` for example.

Or you can create your own implementation of ProfileValueSource:

As `@IfProfile` looks by default in System Properties, you need to provide implementation of `ProfileValueSource` to read from any property source. Note below example still looks into system properties - this just an example of custom resolver.

```
public class MyProfileValueSource implements ProfileValueSource {
  private final Properties testProperties;

  public MyProfileValueSource() {

      ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("test.properties");
      if (resource.exists()) {
          try {
              this.testProperties = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource);
          } catch (IOException e) {
              throw new RuntimeException(e);
          }
      } else {
          testProperties = new Properties();
      }
  }

  @Override
  public String get(String key) {
      return testProperties.getProperty(key, System.getProperty(key));
  }
```

and then refer to it in your test class

```
@ExtendWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyApplicationConfig.class)
@ProfileValueSourceConfiguration(MyProfileValueSource.class)
public class ServiceTests {

  @Test
  @IfProfileValue(name = "test.enabled", value = "true")
  public void test() {

  }
}
```

You can provide any implementation you of `ProfileValueSource` you need (i.e. read from any other property source)

Comment: I tried `@SpringJUnitConfig
@ActiveProfiles("test")` but the JUnit tests are executed.

Comment: It will take time. By the way it's pretty much that I pasted above. I will add the maven dependencies.

Comment: ActiveProfiles will only control which beans are loaded into context. 
If you need to define which tests to run use @IfProfileValue.

Comment: @PeterPenzov Please see update answer above.